# Python/Pygame: How to break a while loop initiated by KEYDOWN event with a KEYUP event?

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, colors, pygame

I am working on an application that lets the user add or subtract from 3 different variables(R,G,B). These variables' values will then be processed and used to draw a picture on screen of the respective color they represent.

In order to accomplish this, I have implemented six different keys to handle this operation: q,w,e and a,s,d. The first three are used for adding to their assigned variables, and the last three are used to subtract from the same assigned variables.

I have managed to accomplish this much, but instead of pressing a key up to 255 times to get to the maximum value, i would like to implement some kind of loop that will continue on as long as a key is pressed, and then stop when a key is no longer being pressed.

The code in question is as follows:

```
def main():
    global keypressed

    while True:

        #Displays current coordinates of mouse
        mouseText=str(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        mousecoordstext = font.render('(X,Y) - '+ mouseText + '      ', 1, (black), (gray5))
        Surface.blit(mousecoordstext, (155,105))

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                keypressed = True #A key is being pressed, initiate loop after figuring out what key it was

                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit
                    sys.exit()

                #Variable Explanations
                #changeType: indicates either subtraction or addition to variable
                #color: indicates what color is being changed

                if event.key == K_q:
                    changeType = 1
                    color = 1                                                   
                elif event.key == K_a:
                    changeType = 0
                    color = 1
                elif event.key == K_w:
                    changeType = 1
                    color = 2                   
                elif event.key == K_s:
                    changeType = 0
                    color = 2
                elif event.key == K_e:
                    changeType = 1
                    color = 3
                elif event.key == K_d:
                    changeType = 0
                    color = 3

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                keypressed = False #A key is no longer being pressed

                #The loop in question is below
                while keypressed: 
                    if keypressed == False: #When a key is no longer being pressed
                        break
                    else:
                        Color_Update(changeType, color)#Calculate color changes                
                        Color_Draw(red, green, blue)#Draw the new color

            pygame.display.update()

main()
```

What I suspect is that I need to somehow check for a pygame event inside of my while loop? Im not sure how to implement this however.

I apologize for possibly asking a similar question, but looking at many questions like this one yielded no results for me, and so i decided to ask it myself for i feel it is different according to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to start a second loop for this. In your main loop, just check if keypressed is still true and apply the changes to your variables. The color change effect should be repeated again and again until a KEYUP event is registered.
So, your main loop would look something like this:

```
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            keypressed = True

            #Set your changetype and color variables

        if event.type == KEYUP:

            keypressed = False;

    if keypressed:

        Color_Update(changeType, color)                
        Color_Draw(red, green, blue)

    pygame.display.update()
```

As always, make sure your frame rate is adjusted so that this happens at a reasonable speed.

Comment: Thank you so much! -- I can't believe such there was such a simple answer to my question. I really over-thought this one. Thanks again!